# Something similar to merge in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Using 2 tables I need to delete distinct, and insert new records.

I've table1 and table2. First 3 records are the same in both tables, but last 2 records are different. So first of all I need to delete different records and after that add new records.

I use SQL Server 2005, so `MERGE` function doesn't exist yet. How could I resolve this without using `MERGE`?

Thank you very much!

```
create table #Table1 (F1 char(5),F2 char(5),F3 char(5))
insert into #Table1
select 'AAA','BBB','CCC' union all
select 'AAA','BBB','CCC' union all
select 'AAA','BBB','CCC' union all
select 'AAA','BBB','DDD' union all
select 'AAA','BBB','EEE'

SELECT * FROM #Table1

create table #Table2 (F1 char(5), F2 char(5), F3 char(5))

insert into #Table2
   select 'AAA','BBB','CCC' union all
   select 'AAA','BBB','CCC' union all
   select 'AAA','BBB','CCC' union all
   select 'AAA','BBB','FFF' union all
   select 'AAA','BBB','GGG' 

SELECT * FROM #Table2
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  What is your desired output?

Comment: @AbeMiessler Table1 will be a normal table and table2 temporal table. I want maintain equal records, delete different records and add new records.

Comment: Workaround: Write a proc with different statements to do update/insert/delete.

Comment: it is impossible to guess what you are trying to do. You have 3 identical rows. How would you ever merge that ? Match(join) on what ?